# Template deduction with another template parameter that has a default value

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

The code below will not compile, because when I want to specify `Param`, type deduction of `A` and `B` is disabled and I would have to specify those explicitly as well.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B>
struct L
{
};

template<typename A, typename B, unsigned Param = 0>
void fn(L<A, B> l_) {}

int main()
{ 
    L<int, float> l;
    fn<3>(l);
}
```

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7beb3ee1d2780421)

Is it possible to have the best of both worlds with deduction of `A` and `B` and yet still be able to provide `Param`, which has a default value in case it is left out?

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course, you just need to put the `Param` argument first (so that you can explicitly specify it):

```
template<unsigned Param = 0, typename A, typename B>
void fn(L<A, B> l_) {}
```

Note that this works even though `A` and `B` don't have default parameters because they can be deduced.

Comment: Wait, this is possible? Hmm

Comment: Yeah, that just blew my mind, because with function parameters this obviously doesn't work